# Transformation to multilabel classification

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to implement a neural network in Python (Keras) that will predict the probability of multiple outcomes. At the moment I have the following code, for simplicity I reduced the problem to 3 inputs and 3 outputs:

```
import keras as k
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_frame = pd.read_csv("123.csv")
input_names = ["Sex", "Age", "IQ"]
output_names = ["OUTPUT1", "OUTPUT2", "OUTPUT3"]

raw_input_data = data_frame[input_names]
raw_output_data = data_frame[output_names]

max_age = 100
encoders = {"Age": lambda age: [age/max_age],
            "Sex": lambda gen: {"male": [0], "female": [1]}.get(gen),
            "IQ": lambda iq_value: [iq_value],
            "OUTPUT1": lambda output1_value: [output1_value],
            "OUTPUT2": lambda output2_value: [output2_value],
            "OUTPUT3": lambda output3_value: [output3_value]}

def dataframe_to_dict(df):
    result = dict()
    for column in df.columns:
        values = data_frame[column].values
        result[column] = values
    return result


def make_supervised(df):
    raw_input_data = data_frame[input_names]
    raw_output_data = data_frame[output_names]
    return {"inputs": dataframe_to_dict(raw_input_data),
            "outputs": dataframe_to_dict(raw_output_data)}


def encode(data):
    vectors = []
    for data_name, data_values in data.items():
        encoded = list(map(encoders[data_name], data_values))
        vectors.append(encoded)
    formatted = []
    for vector_raw in list(zip(*vectors)):
        vector = []
        for element in vector_raw:
            for e in element:
                vector.append(e)
        formatted.append(vector)
    return formatted


supervised = make_supervised(data_frame)
encoded_inputs = np.array(encode(supervised["inputs"]))
encoded_outputs = np.array(encode(supervised["outputs"]))

train_x = encoded_inputs[:300]
train_y = encoded_outputs[:300]

test_x = encoded_inputs[300:]
test_y = encoded_outputs[300:]

model = k.Sequential()
model.add(k.layers.Dense(units=5, activation="relu"))
model.add(k.layers.Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid"))
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="sgd", metrics=["accuracy"])

fit_results = model.fit(x=train_x, y=train_y, epochs=100, validation_split=0.2)

plt.title("Losses train/validation")
plt.plot(fit_results.history["loss"], label="Train")
plt.plot(fit_results.history["val_loss"], label="Validation")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

plt.title("Accuracies train/validation")
plt.plot(fit_results.history["accuracy"], label="Train")
plt.plot(fit_results.history["val_accuracy"], label="Validation")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

predicted_test = model.predict(test_x)
real_data = data_frame.iloc[300:][input_names+output_names]
real_data["POUTPUT1", "POUTPUT2", "POUTPUT3"] = predicted_test
print(real_data)
real_data.to_csv('C:/***/133.csv')
```

I need help implementing the output of probabilities for all 3 outcomes [POUTPUT1, POUTPUT2, POUTPUT3] (currently outputs only 1) and saving them in a table like this one:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adapt input and output of your model, and change your sigmoid output activation for an activation that supports categories (softmax for example) Try something like this:

```py
INPUT_DIM = 3
OUTPUT_DIM = 3

# first define your model
model = k.models.Sequential()
model.add(k.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu',  input_dim = INPUT_DIM ))
model.add(k.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'))
  ## you can add more layer if you want, to customize your model
model.add(k.layers.Dense(OUTPUT_DIM, activation='softmax'))

# then compile
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="sgd", metrics=["accuracy"])

# then fit
fit_results = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=100, validation_split=0.2)
```

---

So, I tested your code with the changes I suggested, and the network seems to work.
Try this :

```py
import keras as k
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_frame = pd.read_csv("123.csv")
input_names = ["Sex", "Age", "IQ"]
output_names = ["OUTPUT1", "OUTPUT2", "OUTPUT3"]

raw_input_data = data_frame[input_names]
raw_output_data = data_frame[output_names]

max_age = 100
encoders = {"Age": lambda age: [age/max_age],
            "Sex": lambda gen: {"male": [0], "female": [1]}.get(gen),
            "IQ": lambda iq_value: [iq_value],
            "OUTPUT1": lambda output1_value: [output1_value],
            "OUTPUT2": lambda output2_value: [output2_value],
            "OUTPUT3": lambda output3_value: [output3_value]}

def dataframe_to_dict(df):
    result = dict()
    for column in df.columns:
        values = data_frame[column].values
        result[column] = values
    return result


def make_supervised(df):
    raw_input_data = data_frame[input_names]
    raw_output_data = data_frame[output_names]
    return {"inputs": dataframe_to_dict(raw_input_data),
            "outputs": dataframe_to_dict(raw_output_data)}


def encode(data):
    vectors = []
    for data_name, data_values in data.items():
        encoded = list(map(encoders[data_name], data_values))
        vectors.append(encoded)
    formatted = []
    for vector_raw in list(zip(*vectors)):
        vector = []
        for element in vector_raw:
            for e in element:
                vector.append(e)
        formatted.append(vector)
    return formatted


supervised = make_supervised(data_frame)
encoded_inputs = np.array(encode(supervised["inputs"]))
encoded_outputs = np.array(encode(supervised["outputs"]))

print(encoded_inputs)
print(encoded_outputs)

train_x = encoded_inputs[:-10]
train_y = encoded_outputs[:-10]

test_x = encoded_inputs[-10:] # I changed this to fit my fake data
test_y = encoded_outputs[-10:] # but you can keep your code.

INPUT_DIM = 3
OUTPUT_DIM = 3

# first define your model
model = k.models.Sequential()
model.add(k.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu',  input_dim = INPUT_DIM ))
model.add(k.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(k.layers.Dense(OUTPUT_DIM, activation='softmax'))

# then compile
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="sgd", metrics=["accuracy"])

# then fit
fit_results = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=100, validation_split=0.2)

# plt.title("Losses train/validation")
# plt.plot(fit_results.history["loss"], label="Train")
# plt.plot(fit_results.history["val_loss"], label="Validation")
# plt.legend()
# plt.show()

# plt.title("Accuracies train/validation")
# plt.plot(fit_results.history["accuracy"], label="Train")
# plt.plot(fit_results.history["val_accuracy"], label="Validation")
# plt.legend()
# plt.show()

predicted_test = model.predict(test_x)
print(predicted_test[0])
```

Then, when i print `predicted_test[0]`, it gives me the outputs :

```py
[[0.9967424  0.00114053 0.00211706]]
```

After that, I don't know exactly what you want to do with the dataframe, but I would try something like :

```py
real_data = data_frame.iloc[-2:][input_names+output_names]
real_data.reset_index(inplace=True)
real_data["POUTPUT1"] = predicted_test[:,0]
real_data["POUTPUT2"] = predicted_test[:,1]
real_data["POUTPUT3"] = predicted_test[:,2]
print(real_data)
# then save it
real_data.to_csv(...)
```

3rd edit to solve your problem, I think it's ok now, the initial question is solve.
You should close this topic and open a new one if you encounter a new issue.

Comment: I probably took Your advice too literally :D
I got an error: https://imgur.com/mdZQkvG
When making: https://imgur.com/NcXzlU6

Comment: Should I make changes at the beginning of my code?

Or did I just incorrectly implement Your advice?

Comment: yes, too literal :) You must first make the model (model.add from input to output), then compile it. I'll edit the message to make it clearer

Comment: I would greatly appreciate it.
I am very interested in the topic for the development of this neural network, but it's hard when there is not enough, both theoretical and practical knowledge.

Comment: I carried over the part of model.add (which is related to OUTPUT_DIM) prior to compilation.

As for the further improvement of the models, this is theoretically understandable. For now, I would like to figure out how to launch it in this form.

But the problem was not eliminated (I even tried to do it according to your form, removed my add-ons).

Comment: Thanks for your hard work. Yes, your code is working.
Am I correct in saying that the end result is a general trend for the three probabilities?

If so, then one more question remains.
How to get these probabilities for each line (as it was originally with one outcome).

If I am speaking incorrectly, then person A may have OUTPUT1, OUTPUT2, OUTPUT3. Which were entered in advance. But how do I get the (projected) OUTPUT1, OUTPUT2, OUTPUT3 into a new .csv file. Accordingly, this should happen for other lines as well.

Comment: In my original work, partially expanded here in the question (besides the actually known result on which the model is trained, a column was created in which the neural network recorded the trend you received, but for each column)

Comment: More specifically, how to ensure the result as I presented in the visualization (with the preservation of the new csv table)

Comment: Edited again. As your the initial problem is solved, please mark it as "solved", and if you have a new questions please open a specific topic referring to a precise issue

Comment: Data frame for personal analysis only. Thank you very much for your time. You are just an excellent specialist.